# Access untranslated string in PyQt?

Tags: pyqt5

I am writing a little pyqt  application. Now I have start using Qtranslator with *.ts and *.qm files to get a Swedish translation.

I use e.g. self.tr(“Test this”) “Swedish Testar detta”. I am wondering while using the Swedish translation, if it is possible to get back the original untranslated string, in this case “Test this” in the program?

This i my little program and I want the "translate_string" method to print the original string.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout)
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QTranslator)


class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Form, self).__init__()
        button = QPushButton(self.tr("&Close"))
        self.test_lang = QPushButton(self.tr("Translate"))
        self.string = self.tr("Test this")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.test_lang)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.test_lang.clicked.connect(self.translate_string)
        button.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def translate_string(self):
        print(self.string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    translator = QTranslator()
    translator.load("test_trans_sv_SE.qm")
    app.installTranslator(translator)
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```